# Force app to start in systray at autostart (in i3wm)

Tags: i3, session, autostart, tray

On i3 I start `qstardict` at the session opening with the following line on the `i3config` :

```
exec  --no-startup-id qstardict
```

So, Qstartdict open its window at each session starting witch is messy. Unfortunately, Qstardict haven’t a built-in option for opening itself in systray.

##### The question

Then, is their any solution to force an app to start in systray?

I read somewhere that this kind of function is highly wm-related. So if needed, my wm is i3wm.

Comment: Since you're on X, you probably can use wmctrl to minimize the application as soon as it starts: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738713/how-do-i-autostart-an-application-on-the-system-tray) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized/663288).